# CodeIgniter - Url amigavel

Tags: php, codeigniter, rotas

Eu estou tentando usar o framework CodeIgnoter.
mas não estou conseguindo passar disso:

```
http://localhost:8087/CodeIgniter/index.php/usuario/home
```

para isso:

```
http://localhost:8087/CodeIgniter/usuario/home
```

Sempre aparece :

```
The requested URL /CodeIgniter/usuario/home was not found on this server.
```

#### Arquivo router:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'usuario';
$route['default_controller'] = 'usuario/home';
```

Comment: No arquivo config.php você já tirou o **index.php** do `$config['index_page'] = '';`. verifica também o arquivo **.htaccess**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para configurar URL amigável no Codeigniter segue os seguintes passos descritos abaixo.

Obs.: Esses passos não são necessariamente sequenciais.

1. No arquivos ./sua_pasta_projeto/application/config/config.php altere o seguinte valor da chave index_page do vetor $config:

De:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Para:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

2. Caso não exista, crie o arquivo .htaccess na raiz do seu projeto (sua_pasta_projeto/.htaccess) com o seguinte conteúdo:

Conteúdo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

3. No mesmo arquivo config.php altere o valor da chave base_url do vetor $config;

Para:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://sua_url_projeto/';
```

No seu caso provavelmente ficará:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8087/CodeIgniter/';
```

Lembrando que você poderá acessar o seu projeto tanto assim:

```
http://localhost:8087/sua_pasta_projeto/index.php/controller/method_action
```

Como:

```
http://localhost:8087/sua_pasta_projeto/controller/method_action
```

Lembrano também que o arquivo route.php serve para configurar rotas personalizadas, não para configurar a URL amigável padrão do Codeigniter.

Answer (score 3):

Altere o config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

para

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Crie ou altere o .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: O meu ta assim tambem e funciona perfeitamente...