# routes do codeigniter 3 não funcionam em produção

Tags: route, codeigniter-3

Estou com um problema com o CodeIgniter 3

No meu ambiente local está funcionando perfeitamente mas quando subo pra produção as rotas não funcionam

Mas se eu colocar index.php na URL vai para a rota correta.

Alguém sabe o que preciso ajustar para funcionar sem index.php?

Exemplo:

Com problema: www.meusite.com.br/contato

Funcionando: www.meusite.com.br/index.php/contato

Comment: Possível duplicata de [CodeIgniter - Url amigavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87625/codeigniter-url-amigavel)

Comment: Talvez vc devesse dar uma olhada na [documentação do framework](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file) pra saber mais detalhes sobre como fazer isso.